# Orientation change event implementation by jquery mobile in phone gap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Could someone please let me know the right code for orientation change event by jquery mobile in phone gap? Where and how do I implement this orientationChange function?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', _orientationHandler);
```

then in the `_orientationHandler` function, have something like:

```
if(event.orientation){
      if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
                  //do something
      }
      else if(event.orientation == 'landscape') {
                    //do something
      }
}
```

Comment: whatever u want to do on orientation change.

Comment: if u see splitview code, u can see what he does to hide one panel in potrait mode

Comment: yups. add css classes... n all

Comment: Current jQuery version recommends `on` event handler: `$(window).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) { }`

Answer (score 12):

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
    if ($.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() == "portrait") {
        //Do whatever in portrait mode
    } else {
        //Do Whatever in landscape mode
    }
});
```

You can add the resize event in the event parameter of the bind function, if you're targeting iOS and orientationchange doesn't work. Since changing orientation fires the resize event too.

Comment: please tell me what i have to do in  "//Do whatever in portrait mode" and  "//Do Whatever in landscape mode"
here only i m confuse....??

Comment: Whatever you intended to do as the phone is in portait mode or in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work across all the browsers to detect orientation change. It doesnt uses jquery mobile event but seems to work for most of devices.

```
1. var isIOS = /safari/g.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
2. var ev = isIOS ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize'; 
3. var diff = (window.innerWidth-window.innerHeight);
4. $(window).bind(ev,function(){
5.     setTimeout(function(){
6.         if(diff*((window.innerWidth-window.innerHeight)) < 0)
7.             orientationChanged();
8.     },500);
9. });
```

Line 2 takes up the resize event for any non-safari browsers since other browsers in other devices take up resize event more consistently than orientation change event.
http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Line 5 performs the check in a timeout since some of the android native browser dont take up the new width immediately.

Line 6 For the orientation change to take place the product of the differences of old and new height and width should be negative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in my mobile templates, as the orientationchange event wasn't triggered on iOS 7 Safari:

```
    // ORIENTATION CHANGE TRICK
    var _orientation = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
    _orientation.addListener(function(m) {
        if (m.matches) {
            // Changed to portrait
            $('html').removeClass('orientation-landscape').addClass('orientation-portrait');
        } else {
            // Changed to landscape
            $('html').removeClass('orientation-portrait').addClass('orientation-landscape');
        }
    });
    //  (event is not triggered in some browsers)
    $(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {
        if (e.orientation) {
            if (e.orientation == 'portrait') {
                $('html').removeClass('orientation-landscape').addClass('orientation-portrait');
            } else if (e.orientation == 'landscape') {
                $('html').removeClass('orientation-portrait').addClass('orientation-landscape');
            }
        }
    }).trigger('orientationchange');
    // END TRICK
```

Comment: with this script you can write css rules easier, based on orientation

Comment: Very useful. Thank you.