# Iframe width issue in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, iframe

I created application using android phonegap and I have loaded aspx page in iframe.I set width 100% for iframe and design is looking fine in onload.But while changing orientation page is not fitted to the device(width for iframe in landscape mode is applied for portrait mode iframe).The design fit to the device when i click the textbox in iframe.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com"); 
iframe.setAttribute("id", "iframeset");
iframe.style.width = 100+"%";
$("#IframeDiv").append(iframe);

<div  id="IframeDiv"></div>
```

please guide me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, capture the screen orientation change event and dynamically reset the width of iframe.

Comment: I have tried orientation change for setting the width.It's not working.It's only working(width is applied) after i am clicking the textbox or any other control in iframe

Comment: See this answer for what I am talking about.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023328/orientation-change-event-implementation-by-jquery-mobile-in-phone-gap

Comment: Hi,I tried this. It's not affecting iframe in orientation change.It's only affecting the iframe after i am focusing textbox or other control in iframe.

Comment: Have you tried by first capturing screen width in a variable and then set the iframe width attribute in pixels rather then in %?

Comment: Hi,I tried this also,I have captured the screen width using $(window).width() and set that width for iframe when changing orientation.but it's only affet focusing the control.I already said in  previous comment